# How to make Yii beforeSave breaks the save

Tags: php, yii, yii-events, yii-behaviour

I would like in some cases the beforeSave in an Yii Behavior to breaks the save and return an error. What I have tried, and not worked is:

```
public function beforeSave($event) {
    parent::beforeSave($event);

    $tested_value = null;

    if(is_null($tested_value)){
        $this->validationErrors = Yii::t('app', 'Ops!  Error');
        return false;
    }
}
```

And in the Controller:

```
        $model=new Post;
        if($model->save()){
            // no matter what this is always executed
        } else {
            print_r($model->validationErrors);die;
        }
```

Comment: is validationErrors variable declare in model class?
like  public $validationErrors

Comment: Yii validates all inputs with rules you shouldn't go to that beforesave action at all .. how ever there is isValid variable and if you set it to false you will prevent save..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecordBehavior#beforeSave-detail): If you override the `beforeSave($event)` method in a `CActiveRecordBehavior`, you have to set the `isValid` property of the `$event` to false, if you want to prevent saving of the owner model.

```
if($preventSave) {
    $event->isValid = false;
}
```

Also note, that it's `$model->errors`, not `$model->validationErrors`.